# XAMPP with Wordpress running too too slow

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, xampp

I am using latest version of xampp and wordpress for development of my new website. Although i am working with xampp and wordpress since couple of years but this new version has frustrated me like anything. Using this new version of Xampp with wordpress is loading one page of the site on local machine in 3-5 minutes. I have tried many changes but really not helping. Can I have some insight over this. This is really annoying and frustrating. Any advice will be lifesaver for me.
My system specs :

```
Processor - Intel(R)Core i5-5200U CPU @2.20GHZ
RAM 8GB
64 Bit OS
Windows 10 Home
```

Errors are not coming but the loading of any page is extremely slow. Internet speed is pretty descent and as its on localhost so it should not worry about that.

Comment: We need some kind of information to deal with it. Please, complete the question with the errors you have at loading, the network conection and all the information you can provide us from the console.

Comment: Thanks @RoyBogado for the concern. I have added some more details . Please look

Comment: I'm talking about the "network" in the F12 browser console, there's any errors there? Show us please.

Comment: There are no such errors on 'Network' tab. its clean. Only warming messages regarding fonts, maps etc

Comment: Well, not the errors, but at least, show us something, becuse we can't guess what's the problem. So, "network" has all the conections your page make for load. If you want to find the "conectivity problem/error" take a look the time that each process long.

Comment: What's the browser you are using?

Comment: Yes processes are taking time to load. Like 1-2 mins for every process

Comment: I a,m using Firefox. But same issue is with Chrome

Comment: Something is wrong with Apache I guess. What could be possibility

Answer (score 0):

In your WordPress wp-config.php file, is the entry for DB_HOST ‘localhost’? If so, change it to ‘127.0.0.1’ and see if it helps.

Another way check your IP address on your local network like 192.168.0.111 Then edit your hosts file like

Change to

```
/etc/hosts 192.168.0.111 mysite.org
```

or try [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/) it is more speed optimized